# Android, программное нажатие на кнопку

Tags: android, android-context-menu

У меня есть `ListView`, мне нужно выбрать пункт в нем и, при нажатии на элемент меню, проделать действия. При этом все должно быть красиво (поэтому я выбрал контекстное меню, а не диалоговую активность, как раньше) и обработчик должен получить позицию нажатого пункта.

Я пришел к варианту, обработать долгое нажатие слушателем `setOnItemLongClickListener`, а в методе `onItemLongClick` вызвать контекстное меню, в которое я смогу передать позицию нажатого элемента. Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что кнопки-то, при нажатии на которою, вызывается контекстное меню — нет! Самым простым вариантом стало создать кнопку (программно, без layout файла) и нажать на нее. Изначально я хотел вызвать метод `onCreateContextMenu`, но там была куча аргументов и я попросту не знаю от куда они берутся, а так же, как без них обойтись или как заменить их.

Так вот, в чем вопрос: как программно произвести долгое нажатие на кнопку, чтобы вызвалось контекстное меню?

```
                                      Не люблю я такую бяку делать, но без нее никак :)).
```

Comment: Если вы вешаете слушатель  longClick на список, то не нужна никакая специальная кнопка. Слушатель сработает при долгом клике на самом айтеме списка. То же и с ContextMenu привязанном к списку - оно вызовется само при долгом клике на айтем - ни то ни другое не надо вызывать явно какой то командой.

Comment: Так же должен заметить, что незнание, как что то сделать правильно, не оправдывает использование каких то костылей, скрытых кнопок и прочих, скажем так, нестандартных, реализаций. Нужно учиться делать правильно, разбираться, а не придумывать "самые простые варианты", тем более, что `onCreateContextMenu` получает всего три параметра, каждый из которых отлично задокументирован. Так же его не нужно откуда-то "вызывать" - он сам вызовется при долгом тапе на айтеме.

Comment: Контекстное меню - базовая функциональность, все просто работает при долгом тапе и просто получает позиции этого тапа. Если у вас не так и вы не знаете, почему у вас не так, как у всех - создавайте вопрос по этой проблеме, а не по костыльным решениям в обход надлежащей функциональности.

Comment: @pavlofff, я уже нашел, как это сделать :).